# Django Model Override Only Works if I Save Twice

Tags: python, django

I have implemented a save override in my model so as to calculate a field using inputs from other models.

In Admin, I have a TabularInline form.

The problem is the code only works if I save my form twice.

Here's my **models.py**

```
class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('school name',max_length=200)
    county = models.ForeignKey(County, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    location = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True, max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
    score = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return'{}'.format(self.name)

    def calc_score(self):
        calculated_score = 0
        for item in Marks.objects.filter(school=self.pk):
            for weight in Weights.objects.filter(year=item.year):
                new_score = item.marks*weight.weight
                calculated_score = calculated_score + new_score
        return calculated_score

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.score=self.calc_score()
        super(School, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And my **admin.py**

```
class MarksInline (admin.TabularInline):
    model = Marks

@admin.register(School)
class SchoolAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        MarksInline,
    ]
```

Comment: How do you know that it works only if you save a model twice? Could you please be more specific about behaviour of your app

Comment: If I edit the formlet and save once, '''score''' does not update. However if I save or edit the formlet a second time, it then updates.

Comment: I guess this is related to save order of models. When School model save method fired, Marks model may not be updated. Can you check the calculation with different marks at two save event and share the score values and what you expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `SchoolAdmin` calls `save_model()` before `save_related()`, so your marks have not been saved when the score gets calculated. I solved it by overriding `save_related()` and calling `School.save()` a second time.

I had to guess at your related tables, but here's a complete, runnable code sample. I added the `save_related()` method.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

""" A Django web app in a single file.

To get it running, copy it into a directory named udjango:
$ pip install django
$ python udjango_web.py

Then browse to http://localhost:8000 and log in to the web site.

Tested with Django 3.0 and Python 3.8.
"""


import os
import sys

import django
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib import admin
from django.core.management import call_command
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.base import ModelBase
from django.http import HttpResponse

WIPE_DATABASE = True
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
DB_FILE = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'udjango.db')

# the current folder name will also be our app
APP_LABEL = os.path.basename(BASE_DIR)
urlpatterns = []


def main():
    setup()

    # Create your models here.
    class County(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

    class Weights(models.Model):
        year = models.IntegerField()
        weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.year)

    class School(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField('school name', max_length=200)
        county = models.ForeignKey(County, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
        location = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True, max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
        score = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

        def __str__(self):
            return '{}'.format(self.name)

        def calc_score(self):
            calculated_score = 0
            for item in Marks.objects.filter(school=self.pk):
                for weight in Weights.objects.filter(year=item.year):
                    new_score = item.marks * weight.weight
                    calculated_score = calculated_score + new_score
            return calculated_score

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.score = self.calc_score()
            super(School, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Marks(models.Model):
        school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        year = models.IntegerField()
        marks = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    # Form classes
    class MarksInline(admin.TabularInline):
        model = Marks

    @admin.register(School)
    class SchoolAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        inlines = [
            MarksInline,
        ]

        def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
            super().save_related(request, form, formsets, change)
            form.instance.save()

    admin.site.register(County)
    admin.site.register(Weights)
    admin.site.register(Marks)
    admin.autodiscover()

    def index(request):
        return HttpResponse(
            "Hello, Django! <a href='admin'>Sign in</a> "
            "as user 'admin', password 'admin'.")

    urlpatterns.extend([
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^$', index, name='homepage')
    ])

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        if WIPE_DATABASE or not os.path.exists(DB_FILE):
            with open(DB_FILE, 'w'):
                pass
            call_command('makemigrations', APP_LABEL)
            call_command('migrate')
            get_user_model().objects.create_superuser('admin', '', 'admin')
        call_command('runserver')
    else:
        get_wsgi_application()


def setup():
    sys.path[0] = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)

    settings.configure(
        DEBUG=True,
        ROOT_URLCONF=__name__,
        MIDDLEWARE=[
            'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
            'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
            'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
            'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
            'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
            'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
            'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
            'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
            ],
        INSTALLED_APPS=[
            APP_LABEL,
            'django.contrib.admin',
            'django.contrib.auth',
            'django.contrib.contenttypes',
            'django.contrib.sessions',
            'django.contrib.messages',
            'django.contrib.staticfiles',
            'rest_framework',
            ],
        STATIC_URL='/static/',
        STATICFILES_DIRS=[
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
        ],
        STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_root"),
        MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media"),
        MEDIA_URL='/media/',
        TEMPLATES=[
            {
                'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
                'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
                'APP_DIRS': True,
                'OPTIONS': {
                    'context_processors': [
                        'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                        'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                        'django.template.context_processors.request',
                        'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                        'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                        'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                    ],
                },
            },
            ],
        DATABASES={
            'default': {
                'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
                'NAME': DB_FILE,
                }
            },
        REST_FRAMEWORK={
            'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
                'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',
            ],
        }
    )

    django.setup()
    original_new_func = ModelBase.__new__

    @staticmethod
    def patched_new(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        if 'Meta' not in attrs:
            class Meta:
                app_label = APP_LABEL
            attrs['Meta'] = Meta
        return original_new_func(cls, name, bases, attrs)
    ModelBase.__new__ = patched_new


main()
```